# Dropbox-like web interface for an FTP server

Tags: ftp, file-sharing, webgui

I am looking for an open-source web-based interface that allows me to share files that reside on an ftp server.

It should also be possible to

a) share folders so that non-registered users with a direct link can upload files

b) embed single shared folders in web pages

Don't know if such a solution exists, but I appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it will do what you want but have a look at [ZendTo](http://www.zend.to/)

> This is a web-based package that will let you provide a secure and easy-to-use method for your users to be able to exchange files with other people, even with people on other sites that do not have any login rights at your site.
>
> Unlike other commercial services, you do not have to trust your files or login rights to any other services; you run all of it yourself. It integrates with your existing authentication system if you have one, or else it can use its own secure SQL-based user authentication system. It will integrate with any Active Directory, LDAP or IMAP system you already have in place.
>
> It was originally based on the "Dropbox" package written by the University of Delaware.

Comment: Great. Thanks for now. Going to install it and see if it does what I need.